# Customizing points to pts in latex exam class

Tags: formatting, exam, customize

I know this is out of convention and norm but I am typesetting an exam and using `points` for each question part and subparts seem to consume a lot of space. How do customize it to `pts` instead of `points`?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please add a code snippet that tells us which document class you are currently using. It should show the output you have described in the question. See: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using the `exam` class, it has a command to set the string it uses:

```
\pointpoints{pt}{pts}
\bonuspointpoints{pt (bonus)}{pts (bonus)}
```

giving the singular and plural forms in each case.